# Inheriting from a control vs Creating a new control template

Tags: wpf, mvvm, custom-controls, controltemplate

I'm creating a WPF application (which is also MVVM based), what should I consider when deciding whether to inherit and create a Custom Control vs creating a new style template for that control.

I should note that all my modified controls should later be used by other developers who will receive them as a separate assembly.

For example - a Watermark Textbox: You can create a [Custom Control](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.co.il/2009/05/watermarktextbox-by-inheriting-textbox.html) or create a [new style](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/wpf-watermark-textbox-using-xaml-style.html) (notice both are from the same blog...).

Are there any "rules of thumb" to help decide on one way vs the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would inherit to add functionality and change templates to change appearance. So if it does something more than the original control i would use a sub-class. (Of course you can also extend functionality via a template to some extent but that is somewhat beside the point.)

Comment: Then how would you classify the Watermark Textbox, for instance?

Comment: @Blachshma: That's pretty much appearance only, so i do not see any need for a new control. If however the watermark is dynamic you could consider it functionality (add a property for the message for example).